# How to plot in a new window in Spyder-IDE(Python)

Tags: matplotlib, ide, window, ipython, spyder

My `Spyder-IDE` prints the plots in it's `ipython console`. How can I change the settings to do plotting on a new pop-up window?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics > Graphics Backend`

and select the option called `Automatic` there.

After doing that you need to restart either Spyder or the console kernel for this change to take effect.

Comment: This also works on newer versions of Spyder IDE. I'm running 5.3.1 and the menu sequence is the same.